# return more than one value in c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I  made a function in c++ that I named it `apply_morph_find_target_func`.
In this function I want to get two values and return one Mat and one dynamic array.
The name of the dynamic array is `target_property`.
The size of `target_property` would be `n*6`, where `n` is dynamic:
[image: target_property]
Here is what I have defined for my function :

```
Mat apply_morph_find_target_func(Mat result_first, Mat im) {
  ...
}
```

what should I do?
regards

Comment: Use reference arguments to return additional values.

Comment: or return a struct/class that contains both values.

Comment: Or return a std::tuple

Answer (score 1):

You can return a structure with mat and a pointer to  array within the structure. And in the main function to excess this values.

```
struct MyStruct{
    int **mat;
    int *arr;
};

MyStruct foo(){
    int n=1;
    MyStruct fooz;
    fooz.mat=new int*[n*6];
    fooz.arr=new int[6];
    return fooz;
}
```

Comment: would you say an example

Comment: Sure, in a hour or so.